# Unable to access PostgreSQL database from remote server but i'm able to access with pgAdmin client

Tags: postgresql, qt

```
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL","MainDB");

db.setHostName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");// remote pc ip
db.setPort(5432);
db.setDatabaseName("Users");
db.setUserName("postgres");
db.setPassword("test");
if(!db.open())
{
   qDebug()<<"Unable to open database";
}
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError - show us the result of `lastError`

Comment: By default, remote access is disabled in postgresql. Have you edited `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files to allow remote access?

Comment: Yes... I'm able to access with pgAdmin but not with my application

Comment: last error is "driver not loaded"

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I copied all DLLs from C:\PosgreSql 9.3\bin to my application and it is working.

Thank You Guys!!!!